# Automate a task in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, automation

I am new in MS SQL Server and i am wondering if there is an automation module in order to automatically for example calculate the mean (average) of sales per month in a database that is being updated every month ?

```
SELECT SUM(prices) MONTH(date)
  FROM myTable
 GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

The result of this automation ideally will make a report and send it with an email or store it in a cloud.

Comment: Calculate and do what with it?

Comment: @Charlieface  make a report and send it with an email or store it in a cloud.I will edit my question i forgot it

Comment: You can create an SQL Server Agent Job and use Database Mail to send create the report and send it. I'm afraid a full tutorial is outside the scope of [so]